# Adjusting iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, ejs

I want to customize the following iframe,

I tried this code:

`<div class="Pagina2" style="display:flex; width:600; height:400">`

Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `width` and `height` in the iframe tag.

Example:

```
<iframe src="/default.asp" width="100%" height="300" style="border:none;">
</iframe>
```